# How do I capture Wifi traffic in the wifi channel spectrum?

Tags: wifi, sniffer, sniffing

How could I capture traffic from every AP near me? For example using `tcpdump` or `tshark` and a channel hopping script(Channel 1-11). Is this possible?
I have tried with `tcpdump` and a channel hopping script, but I couldn't capture any "actual data".
However when I used a fixed channel I could capture HTTP/TCP requests from devices on an AP in that channel.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Is your WiFi adapter in monitor mode?

Comment: @Joe yes it is.

Comment: You won't get all traffic with one radio.  You might see some traffic on a channel, but you will miss most of it during the hopping, when the radio is tuned to a different frequency.  The #wificactus is one (awesome but rather silly) solution to the problem: http://palshack.org/the-hashtag-wifi-cactus-wificactus-def-con-25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to sniff 802.11 traffic, right?

Use Wireshark in Monitor Mode. When you're the menu, there should be a cog. Tick the box near Monitor, then start sniffing. You should see beacon frames and things. Also, I've written a little guide below to help you decrypt the traffic.

[Disclaimer: Please use this for educational purposes. I am not responsible for any damage you use this for. Sniffing 802.11 packets is legal as long as it has no criminal intent.]

To decrypt the traffic, you must have an 4 way handshake (EAPOL) and the WiFi password. See some things below.

Tip: Preferences > Protocols > IEEE 802.11 > Decryption Keys > (+)

The key type would be WPA2 or WEP for example. The key would have the SSID and the password.

For example, you would have it in the format of PASSWORD:SSID. Make sure to enable decryption!